# Differet behavious of Appbundle and APK in flutter release build

Tags: android, flutter

My Flutter app behaves strangely. On some devices it freezes on startup after installation and then works fine after the app data around 350 kb is cleared and the app is relaunched. This is charachteristic of the appbundle. If you install APK it works fine from the first launch. Also the behaviour is limited to some devices. Most are ok. Any steps to debug?

UPD: we found the code that malfunctions on specific devices, but the question remains, how the same code works fine in apk and is compromised in appbundle for specific devices

Comment: with respect to apk , flutter apk's size is large. but flutter code works similar to all devices . can you explain in more detail means I can help